# Who pays for the travel for Heisman trophy nominees?

Tags: american-football, collegiate, awards

When a player is nominated to receive the [Heisman Trophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisman_Trophy), he and sometimes his family appears at the trophy presentation.  Who pays for this travel?

Comment: As far as I know the people who "run" the award show pay for the student athletes to attend.  Granted I don't have any proof as of yet, so I'll try and find some.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that can be said for certain is **NOT the [Heisman Trophy Trust](http://www.heisman.com/)**, the organization presenting the award. They are considered a non-profit charitable organization and tax-exempt therefor [can only give money to other tax-exempt organizations.](https://www.forbes.com/sites/williampbarrett/2010/12/11/heisman-trophy-trust-is-one-stingy-charity/#6782a9c77e2c)

Other than that all parties involved are going to be making money... lots of money. [Source for below examples](https://www.sportsbusinessdaily.com/Daily/Issues/2012/12/07/Marketing-and-Sponsorship/Heisman.aspx).

The school may for the trip as the athlete is part their organization and I'm sure they can justify those expenses as "football related".

> Baylor Univ. estimates that Robert Griffin III's Heisman Trophy win last year was worth $250M in "extra donations, increased ticket sales, licensing fees, sponsorship deals [and] an expanded deal with Fox Sports Southwest," according to Michele Steele of ESPN.com. <sup>[3](https://www.sportsbusinessdaily.com/Daily/Issues/2012/12/07/Marketing-and-Sponsorship/Heisman.aspx)</sup>

The athlete may pay their own way as they will likely be receiving a windfall by becoming a marketable commodity;

> Pro Stars Ink President Ben Litvin estimates a Heisman winner "can pull down about $50,000 a year from three to four autograph sittings a year, three to four corporate appearances a year, two to three paid golf appearances per year, and three speeches" <sup>[3](https://www.sportsbusinessdaily.com/Daily/Issues/2012/12/07/Marketing-and-Sponsorship/Heisman.aspx)</sup>

Or it could be sports agents looking to do the athlete a "favor" in return for being selected to represent the player during their professional career.

> The governing agency of college athletics said he [2005 Heisman winner Reggie Bush] and his family accepted huge amounts of money and perks from sports agents--including a limousine ride to the Heisman ceremony. <sup>[2](https://www.forbes.com/sites/williampbarrett/2010/12/11/heisman-trophy-trust-is-one-stingy-charity/#6782a9c77e2c)</sup>